# If $M/N\cong M$, can we conclude that $N=0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be an $R$-module, where we may assume that $R$ is an integral domain.

Let $N$ be a submodule of $M$.

Suppose that $M/N\cong M$. Can we conclude that $N=0$?

(If no, what are some sufficient conditions that make it true?)

Update: I learn that for "infinite dimensional" cases it can fail. How about when $M$ is finitely generated, does it work?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is false, but see statement 3 of [Nakayama's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama%27s_lemma) on wikipedia.

Comment: *how about when $M$ is finitely generated, does it work?*  Nope. You can get $R\oplus R\cong R$ as $R$ modules for some rings. This is clearly finitely generated with a quotient by a nonzero ideal isororphic to $R$.  See egreg's answer in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

It fails for vector spaces of infinite dimension.

Answer (score 2):

It is not true. Let $M = \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{Z}$, and let $N = \{(z,0,0,0,\ldots)\,|\, z \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Then $M/N \cong M$.

Comment: How about when M is finitely generated, does it work?

Comment: If $M$ is a vector space, then yes it does. If $M$ is not a vector space, then I'm not so sure...

Comment: It still holds if we let $R = \bigoplus^\infty \mathbb Z$, while $M=R$, and $N$ stays the same. I believe $R$ and $M$ need to be Noetherian for that to hold.